# Linear dependence relations in $R$-modules (of polynomials)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules

Some of the hypothesis on gradedness might be redundant but I explicit them in order to let the context in which I am working clear enough in case that could help.

Let $M$ be an $\mathbb{N}$-graded free $R$-module ($R$ a graded commutative $k$-algebra with $1$ and of infinite cardinality) and suppose that $G:=\{m_{1},\dots, m_{r}\}\in M_{e}$ for some integer $e$ generates $M_{\geq e}$ as an $R$-module. If $G$ is not a basis, then we have some linear dependence relations of the form $$\sum_{i=1}^{r}a_{i}m_{i}=0$$ with some $0\neq a_{i}\in R.$ My question is if there is a meaningful way to coumpute (maybe up to multiplication by a scalar in $R$ or degree) *how many* of these dependence relations are there.

I would be interested in being able to say something like there is a finite number of them (up to some equivalence) for some concept of finiteness that we could introduce. In general, I am interested in finding up to some interesting equivalence relation how many of these linear dependence relations are there among the elements of the generating set $G.$

Comment: Are you familiar with the machinery of [syzygies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_syzygy_theorem)? If you have generators for a module, the relations between them are the number of "syzygies". Of course, some of these relations are redundant (as you've mentioned, you can scale any relation by a nonzero element in $r$, etc) and it turns out there are "higher order" syzygies which measure relations between relations.

Comment: (continued) There are lots of tools (such as [Macaulay2](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.15/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_computing_spsyzygies.html)) which will happily compute the dimension of a syzygy for you, which seems like a natural way to measure what you're interested in. You can find more information [here](https://www.ams.org/notices/200604/what-is.pdf), for instance ^_^